# Arrow not required (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I do not understand the presence of the red arrow in the table

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\xtext/\ytext in{0/x/y,1/1/4,2/1.5/6,3/2/8,4/5/20}
{\draw (\x,0.5) +(-0.5,-0.25) rectangle ++(0.5,0.25) ;
\draw (\x,0) +(-0.5,-0.25) rectangle ++(0.5,0.25);
\node[]  at (\x,0.5) {$\xtext$};
\node[]  at (\x,0)   {$\ytext$};
}
\draw[color=red,->,thick,>=stealth,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (4.5,.65) edge [distance=1.2cm,bend left=80 ] node [right]{$\times 4$} (4.5,-.15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `edge` is a separate path which inherits, by default, all the attributes of its parent. Hence, an arrow tip is added to the main path and to the `edge`. However, you want it only for the `edge`. Hence, just don't add it to the main path.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x/\xtext/\ytext in{0/x/y,1/1/4,2/1.5/6,3/2/8,4/5/20}
  {\draw (\x,0.5) +(-0.5,-0.25) rectangle ++(0.5,0.25) ;
    \draw (\x,0) +(-0.5,-0.25) rectangle ++(0.5,0.25);
    \node[]  at (\x,0.5) {$\xtext$};
    \node[]  at (\x,0)   {$\ytext$};
  }
  \draw[color=red,thick,>=Stealth,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (4.5,.65) edge [distance=1.2cm,bend left=80, -> ] node [right]{$\times 4$} (4.5,-.15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: just the one arrow]

Alternatively, you can avoid using an `edge`. Then you have just one path and Ti*k*Z will use just one arrow tip, as noted in [balcinus's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390760/).

Comment: also  can define  `every edge/.style={draw,-stealth}` and than write `edge [distance=1.2cm,bend left=80 ] node [right]{$\times 4$} (4.5,-.15);`

Comment: @Zarko True, but this has the look of a one-off arrow to me, given the context. But that would make sense in other cases.

Comment: @Zarko In truth, there is no reason for an edge here, after all ;).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why it is there either, but it disappears if you write
    `(4.5,.65) to [distance=1.2cm,bend left=80 ] node [right]{$\times 4$} (4.5,-.15);` instead of
    `(4.5,.65) edge [distance=1.2cm,bend left=80 ] node [right]{$\times 4$} (4.5,-.15);` (Notice `to` instead of `edge`)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \x/\xtext/\ytext in{0/x/y,1/1/4,2/1.5/6,3/2/8,4/5/20}
      { 
        \draw (\x,0.5) +(-0.5,-0.25) rectangle ++(0.5,0.25) ;
        \draw (\x,0) +(-0.5,-0.25) rectangle ++(0.5,0.25);
        \node[]  at (\x,0.5) {$\xtext$};
        \node[]  at (\x,0)   {$\ytext$};
      }
      \draw[color=red,->,thick,>=stealth,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (4.5,.65) to[distance=1.2cm,bend left=80 ] node [right]{$\times 4$} (4.5,-.15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is because `to` is part of the same path, whereas `edge` constructs a separate path with the same attributes. So you get two arrow tips with `edge`, if you specify `->` for the parent path, but only one with `to`, which is just part of the same path. Alternatively, you can add the tip only to the edge (or override the arrow just for a particular edge, if that's needed in other cases).

Comment: Yes, but in this case the change was just too small and I thought a complete MWE would make it harder to spot the tiny change.

Comment: Done. Hope it's better now.

Comment: Yes, thank you for editing. If I could vote up again, I would, but the system won't let me :(. I've cleaned up my comments asking for the code you've supplied, though ;-).